# Android keyboard covering edit text

Tags: android

I have an edit text in my page and I need to adjust screen to show the values typing in it.

I have action bar in my page and I have given `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"` .

When I run the app, I touch on my edit text and keyboard pops up. The edit text comes on top of the keyboard now which is right. But when I start typing this edit text goes down the keyboard.

This doesn't happen in all devices. In Samsung S3 its having this issue. How to solve this? Please help me out.

Edit:

My edit ext code is as below:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/empId"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: how about using ScrollView ?

Comment: please post your code...

Comment: @Megamind My complete layout is inside a scrollview only.

Comment: @HarshitRathi please find my edit text code

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.what i did was , iadded a linear layout below the root layout like this

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/footer_for_emoticons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/keyboard_height"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Then in  the activity

```
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        Rect r = new Rect();
                        activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView()
                                .getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
                        if (lastDiff == heightDiff)
                            return;
                        lastDiff = heightDiff;
                        Log.i("aerfin","arefin "+lastDiff);
                        if (heightDiff > 100) { //Assume keyboard is present 
                            emoticonsCover.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            flag2 = 0;
                        } else {
                            if (flag == false)
                                flag2 = 1;
                               emoticonsCover.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The linear layout will provide the gap and in manifest add   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  to the activity.Check whether it helps